# Angular Equivalent of WPF ListView DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector

Tags: angular

As a WPF developer currently writing an application in Angular, I'm having a hard time finding the equivalent functionality of the [WPF ListView together with DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector](http://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-listview-itemtemplateselector). With this feature, I can just bind a list of objects of various types, and define a data template for each type. I can also create a class that selects the appropriate data template based on the item.

In the end, I to display a list of various components based on a list of data objects I pass into it. I haven't found an Angular equivalent with this feature, so I want to build my own component.

The most promising solution I found [here](https://www.sparkbit.pl/generalizing-components-angular/) using `ngFor` and `template`.

I found [another way](https://dev.to/mustapha/angular-build-more-dynamic-components-with-ngtemplateoutlet-3nee) using `ngFor` with `ng-container` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

With Angular 9 and the Ivy engine, I have learned that it is now possible to dynamically create components.

What is with the current Angular version the best way to accomplish this?